# When the OP does not ask for a biblical answer, does that mean that answers giving only a biblical answer would be deleted?

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers

When an OP asks, for example, a question about Catholicism, requesting Catholic-based answers, would it be okay for a Catholic to give a biblical answer she or he understands the Catholic church to be in agreement with?

Or would it be necessary to quote a Catholic source that gives those biblical points, or cites the Bible references?

Or would it be necessary for the OP to state that biblical points would be acceptable, to remove risk of that purely biblical answer from a Catholic being deleted?

This could apply equally the other way around, of course. If a question about Protestantism, seeking Protestant-based answers, but not adding that purely biblical answers would be acceptable, mean that purely biblical answers from Protestants would be removed?

Comment: I think this question is largely a duplicate of our older one on citing sources, but we can reopen it if you think it is more distinct.